# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT multiple fields

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I'm probably having a no-brain moment.

I want to return a series of numbers using GROUP_CONCAT from two fields in my database. I have done this so far using the following:

```
SELECT t_id,
CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s_id),',',IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i_id),'')) AS all_ids
FROM mytable GROUP BY t_id
```

This works fine but if i_id is NULL then of course I get an unnecessary comma. Is there a better way to do this so I don't end up with a comma at the end if i_id is NULL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) to avoid extra `comma` for `NULL` values, try this:

```
SELECT t_id,
       CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s_id),
                 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i_id)) AS all_ids
FROM mytable
GROUP BY t_id;
```

Comment: That would replace any double commas (,,) with a single one (,) but that isn't my problem. If the i_id is null I end up with a result such a 2,6,8, when what I need is 2,6,8

Comment: The problem is that if there are duplicates between the 2 fields (s_id and i_id), the distinct on each separate field is not going to help