# GROUP_CONCAT multiple fields in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

How can I do something like:

```
SELECT ID, Store, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(keyword::VARCHAR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Store ORDER BY num ASC) AS keywords, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(url::VARCHAR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Store ORDER BY num ASC) AS urls 
FROM table_name
```

I get the following errors when I run the above query:

> cannot specify more than one user-defined transform function in the SELECT list

I tried [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781784/mysql-group-concat-multiple-fields) but that seems like a MySQL thing. I also believe `GROUP_CONCAT` is no longer support for vertica 7.1.x, so if there is a better way to do this, I am open to that.

Comment: As the message says you cannot  have more than one UDTF in the select list. Maybe two distinct selects and a union in between?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states you can only have one UDTF in a single select statement, so to get around this you can split the query into two sub-queries and join them together.

```sql
SELECT x.ID, x.Store, x.keywords, y.urls
FROM (
        SELECT
                ID,
                Store, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(keyword::VARCHAR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Store ORDER BY num ASC) AS keywords
        FROM table_name
) x
JOIN (
        SELECT
                ID, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(url::VARCHAR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Store ORDER BY num ASC) AS urls
        FROM table_name
) y
        ON x.ID = y.ID
;
```

This will evaluate each query with its own `GROUP_CONCAT` function separately and then join them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `GROUP_CONCAT` at the [Vertica github strings package](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package).  You should be able to just `make` and `make install` if your vsql path is set up right.

Another alternative would be to use `agg_concatenate` which is included in the examples directory.  You'd have to finagle the sql a little to get the ordering in the concatenation correct, though. You can see examples of how to do this in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38107711/3148478).

Answer (score -1):

You will need to handle the transformation of keyword and url in a saparate CTE and pass those through to the group_concat...

```
    With cte_table_name AS (
    SELECT 
        ID
        ,Store
        ,keyword::VARCHAR AS keywords
        ,url::VARCHAR AS urls 
    FROM table_name 
   )
SELECT 
    t.ID    
    ,t.Store 
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(c.keyword) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.Store ORDER BY num ASC) AS keywords 
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(c.url) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.Store ORDER BY num ASC) AS urls 
FROM 
    table_name t
JOIN 
    cte_table_name c
    ON c.ID = t.ID
    AND c.Store = t.Score
```

Comment: Transformations are allowed in UDTFs, but having multiple UDTFs in the same select statement is not allowed, so this solution still will not work.